# Does .set() on an existing document trigger onUpdate or onCreate?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

The title explains the question. I am just wondering if calling set() on a document that exists will trigger the onUpdate or onCreate triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions) is fairly clear about this:

> onCreate:     Triggered when a document is written to **for the first time**.
> onUpdate: Triggered when a document already exists and has any value changed.

So, what you are describing will trigger onUpdate.

This should be easy to validate on your own - simply write one trigger of each type with the same document match pattern and see which one executes as a result of running your client code.